# Which Android phones have Large screen sizes

Tags: android, size, screen

I am trying to figure out which phones have a Large screen size in terms of Android development. Going through the documentation it is a very confusing situation as the Large category also depends on the density of the pixels in the phones screen.
From what I've read it looks like both the EVO and Droid X (who have big screens) are classified as Normal screens with High Density.

Which phones are MDPI/HDPI but also Large Screens?

My endgame here is to support only HVGA and WVGA screens but I need to make sure I'm not cutting a large portion of the market out.

Comment: For those of you talking layouts - they're not applicable here because I'm not using them, the project is a game which must take up the entire screen. Hence the need to limit to certain sizes. Sorry I should have been more clear originally.

Comment: tablets belongs to large screen sizes, not phones. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK tablets, like the Galaxy of Samsung, have large sizes. In fact, you will want to create separated resources for those kind of devices (you know, `values-large`, `layout-large`, `raw-large`, etc.)

Comment: @user432209 It makes sense that the Galaxy Tab is Large because its running 2.3 and XLarge isn't available for it to use. @Cristian do you know of any others using Large? I'm not using layouts btw, please read my new comment on my question.

Comment: Didn't XLarge get introduced in 2.3?

Comment: @user432209 ooops thats a typo on my part. The Tab is running 2.2 Froyo. XLarge was introduced in 2.3 Gingerbread

Answer (score 2):

You can use this site to search for Android phones (any phone actually) with various screen sizes:

http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdachooser

You can also check here to see what percent of the market has a certain screen density:

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

Comment: This chart always confused me because the % of large screens on the market is 0.0%.  How can that be possible?

Comment: @user432209 The dashboard only shows devices which have access to the market (which is where your app would normally be found).  I don't think any tablets have access to the market yet. I could be wrong about that though. Thats why the first link I gave may be better for this situation.

Comment: I would take that chart (on the google dev site) with a grain of salt if I were you since it hasn't been updated since `August 2, 2010`.  They keep updating the versions chart but not the screen size one, sigh. also I believe google.com/phone is a better resource for looking at android phones, but they don't give the density and screen classifications I'm interested in.

Comment: @smith324 Thanks for that other link - I had no idea it existed.  It does seem to be a great resource for phones but it only had one tablet.  The site I provided has everything, very specific search capabilities(you can search by resolution or screen size) and if needed can go beyond android phones.  I didn't realize that the chart hadn't been updated in a while - good call (+1).

Comment: its a good resource and they do provide screen resolution and size but not how Android classifies them. The classification system is vague at best you can look at it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range  Its the overlap between Normal and Large that bothers me the most, which make me wonder which phones are classified (if any) as Large

Answer (score 1):

Best way to know whether the phones are large screen small screen or medium screen devices is to create a new android project.Place your drawables , layouts etc in the respective folders.For eg: place your layouts in the folders like layout, layout-hdpi,layout-large-hdpi,layout-large-tvdpi(for nexus7),layout-xlarge-hdpi etc.similarly have your drawables placed in the corresponding drawables folder. with an identifier in the layout or in the drawable just to know which layout and drawables are rendered on the device on which you are running your app.